# Redirecting child process input / output using named pipes

Tags: c++, c, winapi, named-pipes

On the MSDN documentation, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx a sample is shown using anonymous pipes.
In the description can be read:

```
"...Note that named pipes can also be used to redirect process I/O."
```

Now, I am struggling to make this happen

For stdin, I do something like

```
serverPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
  szPipeName,
  PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
  PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
  1,
  sizeof(TCHAR) * BUFSIZE,
  sizeof(TCHAR) * BUFSIZE,
  PIPE_TIMEOUT,
  lpSa );  //lpSa has its inherited attribute set, just like in the msdn sample.

clientPipe = CreateFile(szPipeName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, lpSa,     OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

Both pipes create fine, later I close the server (parent process) pipe

```
CloseHandle(serverPipe);
```

So the call to ConnectNamedPipe does not return error "there is already a process at the other end of the pipe".

Here is the code for ConnectNamedPipe

```
do
{
  bSuccess = ConnectNamedPipe(serverPipe, &ol);
  if (!bSuccess)
  {
    DWORD dwCode = GetLastError();
    if (dwCode == ERROR_NO_DATA) continue;
    if (dwCode == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED) break;
    report_error(NULL);
  }
} while (!bSuccess);
```

The problem is that it always returns error with ERROR_NO_DATA (The pipe is being closed). So never finished the loop.

NOTE: I need to inherit to the child process the handles to the pipes already opened, because I dont have the source of the children and thus cannot change it.

So, can someone point the right way to do this? or the a full working sample using named pipes for IO redirection for a child process using Win32 API?

PS. The reason I need named pipes is because I want to use Overlapped IO, which doesnt seem to be configurable in anonymous pipes.

Comment: Why don't you take the example from MSDN and use `CreateNamedPipe()` instead of `CreatePipe()` and then work from there? Moreover, do you have a MCVE?

Comment: I am using that example, and modifying it using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365588(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'll work in a MVCE (small sample, thx)

Comment: It sounds as if you're closing `serverPipe` *before* you call `ConnectNamedPipe` ?  (You can't do that.)

Comment: Do you have the server code? The parent process is the one who allows the children to inherit handles, take a look to `CreateProcess`'s documentation.